# iPhone Gestures Adding 2 at once

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, gesture-recognition

**Objective C** answers are fine too. This is in C# Monotouch.

Currently I am using this code to add 2 gestures (left / right) to my WebView. Works fine.

Can I combine this into less code though to indicate that both gestures go to the same action?

```
//LEFT
UISwipeGestureRecognizer sgr = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer ();
sgr.AddTarget (this, MainViewController.MySelector);
sgr.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left;
sgr.Delegate = new SwipeRecognizerDelegate ();
this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (sgr);

//RIGHT
UISwipeGestureRecognizer sgrRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer ();
sgrRight.AddTarget (this, MainViewController.MySelector);
sgrRight.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
sgrRight.Delegate = new SwipeRecognizerDelegate ();
this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (sgrRight);
```

Comment: What language is this? Please tag the question with whatever it is.

Comment: I found if I OR them together that I have to AND out the response in the selector. That works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this version, which is shorter and takes advantage of C# lambdas:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer sgr = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer ();
sgr.Action = delegate {
   // Your handler goes here
});
sgr.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left | 
                UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (sgr);
```

Comment: Err, for me UISwipeGestureRecognizer does not have an "Action" property...? How is that possible? I have that latest MT.

Answer (score 0):

In ObjC you'd use the bitwise or operator with the directions to include them both. But as for whichever language you're using, you'll be lucky to get much support from any experienced iOS developer.